# Why can't I see some chinese characters (eg: ) on macOS BigSur 11.2.1?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, google-chrome, language

For example, when this character: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%A6%B3%8A#Chinese

On Chrome, I see nothing on the web site render:

[image: chrome render of]

and on the address bar:

[image: chrome address bar render of]

If I copy-and-paste the "invisible" character on my Terminal, I see a question mark:

[image: CLI render of]

Finally, I'll copy the character here in case it helps: .

The same happens for many other Chinese characters, as you can see here:

[image: other non-rendered characters]
source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E6%9C%88

Any way I can install something to make this work? Thanks!! 谢谢！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display of any unicode character requires that your machine has a font installed which contains the glyph for it. Apple doesn't provide fonts for all 130000 unicode characters, so when there is one you can't see it normally means you have to download and install an extra font.

[This page](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26cca/fontsupport.htm) gives you a list of fonts that will show the example you give, U+26CCA.